# Botium If Else condition like statement for Alexa responses

Tags: javascript, automation, bots, chatbot

User Input : **Get my American bank transaction**

Alexa response 1 : **Your transaction are as follows ....**

or it can be

Alexa response 2 : **I can't answer that right now. Why don't you try something else?**

My intent here is

```
If (user input is "Get my American bank transaction" )

then Alexa response is "Your transaction are as follows ...."

else (it must give the default response (i.e)

I can't answer that right now. Why don't you try something else?)
```

Now i'll take an example

> Me :Get my American bank transaction
>
> Alexa : Your transaction are as follows ....
>
> else (this fallback response i must be able to add in any response
>   (ie)can i give 2 ".UTT file" reference under bot response)
>
> Default_UTT (this contains "I can't answer that right now. Why don't
>   you try something else?" )

Conclusion
Even if we're not getting the expected response atleast the default response is hit

> > Is this Possible in Botium ????
> >     In my skill I'm either getting any one of the above if i'm not getting the expected response then i need botium to consider the default response

Answer (score 0):

No, branching within a convo file is currently no possible with Botium, and I think it never will, as it is against the Botium philosophy "one conversation path = one test case". For your case, I recommend to split it up in two separate test cases:

**convo 1:**

```
#me
Get my American bank transaction

#bot
Your transaction are as follows
```

**convo 2:**

```
#me
Get me something else

#bot
I can't answer that right now. Why don't you try something else?
```

Comment: Our application is dynamic in nature .
It can be the same utterance if the correct response isn't received then the default response is thrown .That's the flow of how it happens .
So for a given utterance it cab either be B for 90% of times or C .So i need to check both .

Comment: I can only repeat my answer from above - we are dealing here with separate test cases, not with one test case. So the 90% is the "happy path", the other 10% are the exceptional cases to be dealt with in other test cases - both pathes are checked, each with a separate set of convo files.